# Arch linux selecting packages

Tags: linux, arch-linux

I'm currently having problems with my arch linux installation, forgot to select a few packages but in the guide they never mention which key do I need to press to select/deselect the packages in the installation screen.

I used to select them but it's been a long time, I don't remember much anymore =/

Or, if there is a way to make pacman recognize the cd as a container of packages that'd be great.

Comment: resolved, its the spacebar

Comment: oist it as an answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When selecting packages in Arch Linux in the "Select Packages", just press the space bar to select/deselect